# Random numbers keep coming out the same, despite random seed being used

Tags: random, fortran

I have the following small piece of code:

```
  REAL(8)       :: x
  INTEGER       :: i

  call system_clock(i)
  WRITE(*,*) 'cpu time', i
  CALL random_seed(i)

  CALL random_number(x)
  WRITE(*,*) 'uniform RandVar', x
```

CPU time is working fine, but every time I run this I get the same uniform `RandVar number = 0.99755959009261719`, almost like `random_number` is using the same default seed over and over again and ignoring random seed.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Ok I've found a way of producing random numbers:                 call system_clock(i)
      CALL srand(i)
      WRITE(*,*) Rand()                 - but still curious as to why the code above doesn't work?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The same seed may well be being used: that is processor-dependent.  The reason for this is that your call to `random_seed` is not setting the seed.

With the reference

```
CALL random_seed(i)
```

the argument `i` is not the (`intent(in)`) seed, but is the (`intent(out)`) size of the seed used by the processor.  This call is like

```
CALL random_seed(SIZE=i)  ! SIZE is the first dummy argument
```

To set the seed you need to explicitly associate with the `PUT` dummy argument: `call random_seed(put=seed)`.  Here the seed is a rank 1 array of size at least `n` where `n` - again processor-dependent - is the size given by `call random_seed(size=n)`.  From your call `i` holds this value.

Full details are given in 13.7.136 of F2008.

A common way to seed the generator is:

```
integer, allocatable :: seed(:)
integer size

call random_seed(size=size)
allocate(seed(size))
! set seed(:) somehow
call random_seed(put=seed)
```

Setting `seed` appropriately is not a simple process.  I don't address how to do that here, but detail can be found in answers to [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23875589/3157076).

Use of `srand()`, which is mentioned in the comments, is non-standard.

Comment: the part *"set seed(:) somehow"* for the poor: `call system_clock(count) $ call random_seed(size) $ allocate(seed(size), source=count+37*[(i,i=0,size-1)]) $ call random_seed(put=seed) $ deallocate(seed)` See http://stackoverflow.com/q/31174367/4279